# Scanning Monitor Models in my office

Tags: networking, domain

Does anyone know a method on how to run an inventory scan of all the monitors/displays in my network/domain? I need to go around the office and write down the model of each monitor, and I wanted to know if there's a better or faster way to accomplish this.

Comment: This will depend on your environment. If it's homogeneous enough this might be answerable. However, you haven't provided enough detail for anyone to know if that's actually the case.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAudit is fairly useful in this regard.  It can generate a vbscript/javascript login script ( pulls the info using WMI, same as above ) that you can push through group policy to pull this information back to the server ( usually running in a LAMP/WAMP stack ).

The downside to using a login script is that, especially when performing a detailed inventory, it's very slow.  OpenAudit can also generate a script that you can run remotely using remoting or using something like psexec that can provide you with the information or output it to a file that you can pull back into OpenAudit.

OpenAudit also doesn't do very well with a large volume.  The interface gets a little clunky and unresponsive.  To be fair, though, I used a prepackaged "development" WAMP stack to run it most recently, so I didn't really provide it with a firm foundation.

The powershell scripts above are much cleaner and less fuss than bothering with OpenAudit, but if you don't write much code, it's an option.  OpenAudit can also integrate with nmap if you don't know what's on your network at all.  I hear good things about NEWT also, but I haven't used it.

Comment: **Open-AudIT will provide the manufacturer, model, serial, size, aspect ratio, edid version and date of manufacture**. You can run the scripts "offline" as well and just read the result file (it's very simple XML). Just copy the script to a USB and run it individually on each PC. Depending on the size of your network this may be the quickest/easiest/simplest way to go...

Comment: We have customers running it on a networks of over 25,000 nodes with no issues :-) Linux native is the way to go (even in a VM).

Comment: Awesome!  I was hoping it was just my quick and dirty WAMP setup that caused the issues.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell with Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor

Some exemple there : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/03/use-powershell-to-discover-multi-monitor-information.aspx

You will have to script something around that to retrieve the information. (pushed by gpo, in the login script, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The Win32_DesktopMonitor class covers this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(v=vs.85).aspx

Try running the following Powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor -ComputerName (the name of the machine) | Select (whatever values you care about, e.g. MonitorMachine,MonitorType)

PS C:\Users\arima> get-wmiobject win32_desktopmonitor | select MonitorMachine,MonitorType,MonitorManufacturer

MonitorMachine                             MonitorType                               MonitorManufacturer
--------------                             -----------                               -------------------
                                           Dell U2312HM (Digital - DVI)              Dell Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little powershell script that will inspect the remote WMI information for an array of computers to display the Computer Name, Description, Monitor Type and Name on screen. Just modify the array in the first line to suit your list of computer names.

```
$ArrComputers = "PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "etc"
foreach ($computer in $ArrComputers) {
    write-host "Computer - $computer"
    $remotewmi = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_desktopmonitor -ComputerName $computer
    $name = $remotewmi.Name
    $type = $remotewmi.MonitorType
    $desc = $remotewmi.Description
    write-host "Name: $name"
    write-host "Monitor Type: $type"
    write-host "Description: $desc"
    write-host ""
}
```

I'm assuming that you have the necessary permissions, and don't have any firewalls blocking your way.

If you run `get-wmiobject win32_desktopmonitor` in a powershell window, you can see what sort of information is available.